# Simplifying a lot of re-used code

Tags: c#

I have an object which is something like

```
public class Foo
{
    public string PassChoiseInfo { get; set; }
    public string FailChoiceInfo { get; set; }
    public string NAChoiceInfo { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a method which returns me the object with the appropriate data which is as follows:

```
public Foo GetInfo(TestName testNames)
{
   int testNameId = testNames.TestId;
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   switch (testNameId)
   {
     case 3:
        var passRecord = testNames.TestItems.Where(ex => ex.TestNamesId == 3 && ex.TestItemName == "Pass")
              .Select(r => new
               {
                  r.TestItemId,
                  r.TestItemName,
                  r.TestItemDirectory
                }).FirstOrDefault();

         foo.PassChoiseInfo = $"{passRecord.TestItemId},{passRecord.TestItemName},{passRecord.TestItemDirectory}";

         var failRecord = testNames.TestItems.Where(ex => ex.TestNamesId == 3 && ex.TestItemName == "Fail")
               .Select(r => new
                {
                   r.TestItemId,
                   r.TestItemName,
                   r.TestItemDirectory
                 }).FirstOrDefault();

          foo.FailChoiceInfo = $"{failRecord.TestItemId},{failRecord.TestItemName},{failRecord.TestItemDirectory}";

          var naRecord = testNames.TestItems.Where(ex => ex.TestNamesId == 3 && ex.TestItemName == "N/A")
                .Select(r => new
                 {
                    r.TestItemId,
                    r.TestItemName,
                    r.TestItemDirectory
                  }).FirstOrDefault();

           foo.NAChoiceInfo = $"{naRecord.TestItemId},{naRecord.TestItemName},{naRecord.TestItemDirectory}";
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;

                //6 more cases
        }

        return foo;
    }
}
```

As you can see in my `GeTInfo` method I keep using the same code with changing the `.where` condition and I have to do this for a lot of cases. Can someone tell me what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add a quick human-readable version of what `GetInfo` should do?

Comment: For starters you could extract the query to a method with a string parameter for the where clause

Answer (score 2):

I'd extract the query to another method which returns the description string that you need.

```
public Foo GetInfo(TestName testNames)
{
   string GetItemDescriptionShortcut(string testItemName)
   {
      return this.GetItemDescription(testNames, testItemName);
   }

   Foo foo = new Foo
   {
      PassChoiseInfo = GetItemDescriptionShortcut("Pass"),
      FailChoiceInfo = GetItemDescriptionShortcut("Fail"),
      NAChoiceInfo = GetItemDescriptionShortcut("N/A")
   }

   return foo;

}

private string GetItemDescription (TestName testNames, string testItemName)
{
    var item = testNames.TestItems
        .Where(ex => ex.TestNamesId == testNames.TestId && ex.TestItemName == testItemName)
        .Select(r => new
        {
          r.TestItemId,
          r.TestItemName,
          r.TestItemDirectory
        }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (item == null) return null; // or empty string

    return $"{item.TestItemId},{item.TestItemName},{item.TestItemDirectory}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One bit of duplicated code you can fix is the delegate being passed to `Select()`:

```
r => new
{
    r.TestItemId,
    r.TestItemName,
    r.TestItemDirectory
}
```

Currently you're making three anonymous instances of this delegate. Instead, you can create the delegate once and save it as a local variable of type `Func<TypeOfR, Foo>`, then pass that variable to `Select()`:

```
Func<TypeOfR, Foo> select = r => new { ... };
// ...
...Select(select).FirstOrDefault();
```

To go a little further, the only thing that actually changes in your three repetitions is the `Where` clause. So, you could define a function that does the boilerplate and takes a `Where` clause or delegate as a formal parameter:

```
Foo GetObject(TestName testNames, Func<TypeOfEx, bool> predicate)
{
    return testNames.TestItems
        .Where(predicate)
        .Select(r => new
            {
                r.TestItemId,
                r.TestItemName,
                r.TestItemDirectory
            }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var failRecord = GetObject(testNames, ex => ex.TestNamesId == 3 && ex.TestItemName == "Fail");
```

Please name the method something more appropriate than `GetObject`, but without knowing more context I can't suggest a good name :)

Now if your `Where` expression is always of the same form, you can go another step further and pass in the values that `TestNamesId` and `TestItemName` should hold as parameters to your method instead of a delegate:

```
Foo GetObject(TestName testNames, string id, string name)
{
    return testNames.TestItems
        .Where(ex => ex.TestNamesId == id && ex.TestItemName == name)
        .Select(r => new
            {
                r.TestItemId,
                r.TestItemName,
                r.TestItemDirectory
            }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please as my knowledge on delegates isn't the greatest

Comment: Why take `Func<T1, T2>` when it's the exact same 2 checks in the 3 `Where`s? I'd just ask for `TestNamesId` and `TestItemName` as parameters

Comment: @Code A "delegate" is C#-speak for a variable that refers to a method. In C you might call it a function pointer. Your `r => ...` expression is a "lambda expression" used to create an anonymous delegate which `Select()` calls. Here I'm showing how you can create the delegate only once and reuse it in multiple calls.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go at this and let you know how I get on

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Sure, you can do that and I edited it into the answer. I'm trying to show the steps from smallest to biggest.

Comment: I'll have to duplicate this here: `GetObject` says to return `Foo` yet it returns an anonymous object, so this doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

It's the solution in delegate style. You can refactor it to pure methods.

```
public Foo GetInfo(TestName testNames)
{
    int testNameId = testNames.TestId;
    Foo foo = new Foo();
        Func<TestItem, dynamic> dynamicBuilder = r => new { r.TestItemId, r.TestItemName, r.TestItemDirectory };
        Func<string, int, TestItem> filteringMethod = (name, nameId) => testNames.TestItems.Where(ex => ex.TestNamesId == nameId && ex.TestItemName == name).Select(dynamicBuilder).FirstOrDefault();
        Func<TestItem, string> formatMethod = record => $"{record.TestItemId},{record.TestItemName},{record.TestItemDirectory}";

        switch (testNameId)
        {
            case 3:
                foo.PassChoiseInfo = formatMethod(filteringMethod("Pass", 3));
                foo.FailChoiceInfo = formatMethod(filteringMethod("Fail", 3));
                foo.NAChoiceInfo = formatMethod(filteringMethod("N/A", 3));
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        case 7:
            break;

            //6 more cases
    }

    return foo;
}
```

Is also possible remove `switch` statement and make the code more generic.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a helper function, that contains the duplicate code.

```
private static dynamic GetDataWithName(TestName testNames, string name)
{
    return testNames.TestItems.Where(ex => ex.TestNamesId == testNames.TestId && ex.TestItemName == name)
    .Select(r => new
    {
        r.TestItemId,
        r.TestItemName,
        r.TestItemDirectory
    }).FirstOrDefault();    
}

public Foo GetInfo(TestName testNames)
{
    int testNameId = testNames.TestId;
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    switch (testNameId)
    {
         case 3:
              var passRecord = GetDataWithName(testNames, "PASS");

          foo.PassChoiseInfo = $"{passRecord.TestItemId},{passRecord.TestItemName},{passRecord.TestItemDirectory}";

          var failRecord = GetDataWithName(testNames, "FAIL");

           foo.FailChoiceInfo = $"{failRecord.TestItemId},{failRecord.TestItemName},{failRecord.TestItemDirectory}";

           var naRecord = GetDataWithName(testNames, "N/A");

            foo.NAChoiceInfo = $"{naRecord.TestItemId},{naRecord.TestItemName},{naRecord.TestItemDirectory}";
                 break;
             case 4:
                 break;
             case 5:
                 break;
             case 7:
                 break;

                 //6 more cases
         }

         return foo;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `GetDataWithName` says to return `YourType` yet it returns an anonymous object, so this doesn't compile

Comment: you need to correct the `GetDataWithName` method. `ex.TestNamesId == 3` should be `ex.TestNamesId == testNames.TestId`

Comment: What about changing return type of `GetDataWithName` from `Foo` to `dynamic`? Does that need to be static?

Comment: @krs No reason why not.